# Get tracking Id magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, shipment-tracking

I want to Get Tracking id when shipping the order, For it, I use "sales_order_shipment_save_after" Observer. And I try but I got the blank array. My code is

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();               
$order = $shipment->getOrder();
$shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection(); 

$tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();

foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {

    $trackNumbers[] = $track->getTrackNumber();

}
```

I also try other solution which is given in the old post but I am not got any result.
I am also try `$observer->getEvent()->getTrack();`  but also got blank in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
//Get shipment details.
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();

//Get shipment tracking info.
$trackingNumbers = array();
foreach ($shipment->getAllTracks() as $track) {
 $trackingNumbers[] = $track->getNumber();
 };
 echo '<pre>', print_r($trackingNumbers);exit;
```